# Migration Error: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, migration

I'm working with Laravel 5.6 and Mysql Version 5.7.3. Everything is working fine in Laravel Vagrant box. But when I deployed my project in VPS hosting with CentOS and run the command "php artisan migrate:refresh" it's raised error like "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: a lter table `products` add unique `products_bar_code_unique`(`bar_code`))". How could I solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things but in the end, this is what worked for me:

In `config/database.php` replace:

```php
'engine' => null',
```

with:

```php
'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',
```

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/syntax-error-or-access-violation-1071-specified-key-was-too-long